# is there any conversion needed to print prn file which have image from Zebra printer ZT410?

Tags: zebra-printers

I have Zebra printer ZT410 model. I want to print a label which consist image and alphanumeric values. I made label design in Zebra Designer software and converted label into .PRN file. Now, when I'm printing this label using .PRN file I got alphanumeric value but it is not printing images and it also change the margin automatically. So is there any solution how can I print it correctly with Images and set margins using .PRN files and Zebra printer.

Answer (score 0):

you can work with the code in http://labelary.com/, there you can set the label dimensions and add an a image, the image will appear converted in the PRN, good luck !